# Running an R script line-by-line

Tags: r

I just found out how to run a R script from the R Console under Windows.

```
source("arrrFile.R")
```

The problem is, this command runs "silently".
How can I run the file command-by-command as I would type it in the console?

Comment: Have you tried `source("arrFile.R", echo=TRUE)`?

Comment: (+1) @caracal, somehow missed that one option :) no need to put `print` into the source file, unless some output is not interesting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use R's built-in debugger; it must be triggered on a function, so a little wrapper is needed:

```
sourceDebugging<-function(f){
 #Function to inject the code to
 theCode<-function(){}
 #Injection
 parse(text=c('{',readLines(f),'}'))->body(theCode)
 #Triggering debug
 debug(theCode)
 #Lift-off
 theCode()
}
sourceDebugging(<file with code>)
```

This is quite handy for debug (gives you a chance to inspect the state after each line), however, will only evaluate in a fresh environment of `theCode` instead of `source`'s default `.GlobalEnv`... this means for instance that the variables made inside will disappear unless explicitly globalised.

Option two is just to emulate writing from keyboard and pressing ENTER... but as caracal pointed out this can be achieved just by `source(<file with code>,echo=TRUE)`.

Comment: (+1) it is also recommendable to write the source files as the functions and then `debug()` `browser()` are helpful :)

Comment: also vanilla, shows how a command execute line by line R-2.12 --vanilla < yourfile.R

Comment: any method to pass also parameters?

Comment: It seems that the numbers are offset by 1 due to the function definition.  Is there a clever way around that?

Answer (score 10):

Open the script file inside your RGui and press **Ctrl+R** to run line by line (you need to press many times though;)). However I would recommend to use [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/) for the convenient work with R. In this case you run line by **Ctrl+Enter**. Or you may modify your script to `print()` (or `cat()`) the objects.